How to handle Fire and Forget Job on server side?
I am not sure, if I am understanding Hangifre correctly.
So I have my Client and it is sending this to the server:
var testModel = new CreateModel();
testModel.App = "example.com/";
testModel.Name = "testname.zip";

var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testModel));

So this is working fine, the job is created and together with the Json testModel argument in the database.
Now I need to do something with the testModel on the serverside. The server is running correctly, but how can I achieve it, that i get the job and do something with it on the server? The database says that the task Succeeded, but yeah I could not fetch it on the server side. I need to work with the data on the Hangfire Server.
I cannot find it in the hangifre documentation.

You sent a string to hangfire server - what do you expect hangfire to do with it ?

In the model, there are many parameters (also an URL). I need to take the URL and have to download a File. Its much more complicated, but to simplify it: I need the Quque and use the parameters to create the URL and download the file on serverside. (edited the OP)

Can you add your hangfire configuration? Is your hangfire serve hosted in different application ?  If so - they have to share the same database - and share assembly where job that you try to execute is defined.

Background jobs in Hangfire are like Azure Functions (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/functions) or Amazon Lambda (https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) - the thing you enqueue needs to be some self-contained task. Think of it as a method that's executed at some arbitrary time in the future.
So you probably want something like
public class DownloadFileJob
{
    public async Task ExecuteAsync(string url, string fileName, PerformContext context, CancellationToken token)
    {
        // do whatever you're trying to do with the URL and file name
    }
}

And you'd enqueue it like so (no need for that model in your question):
var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue<DownloadFileJob>(m => m.ExecuteAsync(url, fileName, null, CancellationToken.None);

The job is serialized when enqueued, then deserialized into a DownloadFileJob object when Hangfire processes the job, which in this case will execute that object's ExecuteAsync() method using the provided arguments.
